# Wear OS: How to retrieve raw PPG data from fossil Gen 6 ? (ACCESS-LOCK SUSPECTED)

Tags: wear-os

I’m trying to retrieve raw PPG data from my Fossil Gen6 smartwatch, like other
developers who have posted questions below.

[Android Wear: How to get raw PPG data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444302/android-wear-how-to-get-raw-ppg-data)

[What is the best way to save and transfer smartwatch sensor data on Android Wear OS (i.e. as CSV)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250275/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-and-transfer-smartwatch-sensor-data-on-android-wear)

After having finished reading through existing relevant posts, I gave it a try to retrieve raw PPG data via SensorEventListener.
However, unfortunately, my Fossil Gen6 wouldn’t return valid numbers!
To do double-check, I also installed the following app, which is a kind of PPG sensor tester app, in the Fossil Gen 6.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.kuprel.heart_monitor

And then, here’s what I got from the app!!

[smartwatch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx6IX.png)

I guess the way to collect raw PPG data of Fossil Gen 6 differs from the previous versions…
Perhaps, some kind of access restriction to the PPG sensor value may have been applied
in the Fossil Gen 6 series.

So, please tell me the proper way to retrieve raw PPG data from Fossil Gen 6.

Thanks in advance.